# Input as a Scanner Variable using getmethods & setmethods

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, getter-setter

I am trying to create a class `Tax` which uses scanner variables to get the salary and tax rate from user and gives a post tax salary using inputs from the user.

The error that I am getting is that The set-method can not be used to use the scanner variable. Kindly suggest solutions.

The code is as below:-

```
package new_version;
import java.util.Scanner;

class Tax
{
    private int salary;
    private double rate;
    private double posttaxsal;

    public int getSalary()
    {
        return salary;
    }

    public double getRate()
    {
        return rate;
    }

    public void setSalary(int newSalary)
    {
        salary = newSalary;
    }

    public void setRate(double newRate)
    {
        rate = newRate;
    }

    public double posttaxsal()
    {
        posttaxsal = salary - (salary*rate);
        return posttaxsal;
    }
}

public class Taxusinginput {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Tax test = new Tax();

        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        Scanner r = new Scanner(System.in);

        test.setSalary(s);
        test.setRate(r);
    }
}
```

Comment: Your functions are expecting an int and a double, not Scanner objects. Use `Scanner.nextInt()` and `Scanner.nextDouble()`.

Comment: Observation: if I were you I would use Double and Integer instead of primitive types. It is also a good practice declare a default constructor. See also immutable objects approach

Answer (score 0):

`setSalary` expects an int argument, not a `Scanner`. You should pass an `int` value to it.

For example :

```
test.setSalary(s.nextInt());
```

The same goes for `setRate`.

Beside that, there's no reason to create two Scanner instances.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Tax test = new Tax();

    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);

    test.setSalary(s.nextInt());
    test.setRate(s.nextDouble());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in my earlier comment, your functions are expecting an int and a double, not Scanner objects.
Use [`Scanner#nextInt()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextInt()) and [`Scanner.nextDouble()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextDouble()).

**Working example:**

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Taxusinginput {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Tax test = new Tax();

        // Use only one scanner
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Enter salary: ");
        test.setSalary(sc.nextInt());

        System.out.print("Enter rate: ");
        test.setRate(sc.nextDouble());

        System.out.println("Post-tax salary: " + 
                test.posttaxsal());

        sc.close();
    }
}

class Tax {
    private int salary;
    private double rate;
    private double posttaxsal;

    public int getSalary() {
        return salary;
    }

    public double getRate() {
        return rate;
    }

    public void setSalary(int newSalary) {
        salary = newSalary;
    }

    public void setRate(double newRate) {
        rate = newRate;
    }

    public double posttaxsal() {
        posttaxsal = salary - (salary * rate);
        return posttaxsal;
    } 
}
```

**Input/Output:**

```
Enter salary: 1000
Enter rate: 0.02
Post-tax salary: 980.0
```